# Route created using java DSL does not give any clue if the routes were executed properly. Using apache AHC compoenet also as one of the component

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, dsl

I have configured my route as shown below. I am not getting exception, but at the same time there is no output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
           public void configure() {
                from("direct:foo")               
                .to("ahc:http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/")
                .to("file:c:/workpro/outbox?fileName=ahc.xml");
           }
        });
        camelContext.start();
    }catch (Exception e1) {
    }           
    }
```

After the execution I should have a folder by name workpro created in c drive. Do you see any issue with the way I have defined the routes.

Many Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer in the from, and set it to `repeatCount=1` if you only want to call it once.

And the start method in non blocking - I just added a sleep 30 second. But see this FAQ for better ways: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
           public void configure() {
                from("timer:foo?repeatCount=1")               
                .to("ahc:http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/")
                .to("file:c:/workpro/outbox?fileName=ahc.xml");
           }
        });
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        camelContext.stop();
    }catch (Exception e1) {
    }           
    }
```

Or instead of the timer you can use direct, but then you would need to send a message to the direct endpoint to trigger your route to run. This is all documented in the Apache Camel getting started, such as http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html. And new users to Camel is recommended to read: http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried this, but it seems I am missing some configuration. I am executing this inside the corporate firewall, so not sure if the issue is because of the proxy setting for AHC component. I know how to configure proxy using blueprint xml but using Java DSL I am not aware how proxy can be set.